# Using IObservable (Rx) as a INotifyCollectionChanged Replacement for MVVM?

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm, system.reactive

I have been looking into using Rx in an MVVM framework.  The idea is to use 'live' LINQ queries over in-memory datasets to project data into View Models to bind with.

Previously this has been possible with the use of INotifyPropertyChanged/INotifyCollectionChanged and an open source library called [CLINQ](http://clinq.codeplex.com).  The potential with Rx and IObservable is to move to a much more declarative ViewModel using Subject classes to propagate changed events from the source model through to the View.  A conversion from IObservable to the regular databinding interfaces would be needed for the last step.

The problem is that Rx doesn't seem to support the notification that an entity has been removed from the stream.  Example below.
The code shows a POCO which uses BehaviorSubject class for the field state.  The code goes onto to create a collection of these entities and use Concat to merge the filter streams together.  This means that any changes to the POCOs are reported to a single stream.

A filter for this stream is setup to filter for Rating==0. The subscription simply outputs the result to the debug window when an even occurs.

Settings Rating=0 on any element will trigger the event.  But setting Rating back to 5 will not see any events.

In the case of CLINQ the output of the query will support INotifyCollectionChanged - so that items added and removed from the query result will fire the correct event to indicate the query result has changed (an item added or removed).

The only way I can think of address this is to set-up two streams with oppossite (dual) queries.  An item added to the opposite stream implies removal from the resultset.  Failing that, I could just use FromEvent and not make any of the entity models observable - which makes Rx more of just an Event Aggregator.  Any pointers?

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace RxTest
{

    public class TestEntity : Subject<TestEntity>, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public IObservable<string> FileObservable { get; set; }
        public IObservable<int> RatingObservable { get; set; }

        public string File
        {
            get { return FileObservable.First(); }
            set { (FileObservable as IObserver<string>).OnNext(value); }
        }

        public int Rating
        {
            get { return RatingObservable.First(); }
            set { (RatingObservable as IObserver<int>).OnNext(value); }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public TestEntity()
        {
            this.FileObservable = new BehaviorSubject<string>(string.Empty);
            this.RatingObservable = new BehaviorSubject<int>(0);
            this.FileObservable.Subscribe(f => { OnNotifyPropertyChanged("File"); });
            this.RatingObservable.Subscribe(f => { OnNotifyPropertyChanged("Rating"); });
        }

        private void OnNotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
            // update the class Observable
            OnNext(this);
        }

    }

    public class TestModel
    {
        private List<TestEntity> collection { get; set; }
        private IDisposable sub;

        public TestModel()
        {
            this.collection = new List<TestEntity>() {
            new TestEntity() { File = "MySong.mp3", Rating = 5 },
            new TestEntity() { File = "Heart.mp3", Rating = 5 },
            new TestEntity() { File = "KarmaPolice.mp3", Rating = 5 }};

            var observableCollection = Observable.Concat<TestEntity>(this.collection.Cast<IObservable<TestEntity>>());
            var filteredCollection = from entity in observableCollection
                                     where entity.Rating==0
                                     select entity;
            this.sub = filteredCollection.Subscribe(entity =>
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Added :" + entity.File);
                }
            );
            this.collection[0].Rating = 0;
            this.collection[0].Rating = 5;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: "The problem is that Rx doesn't seem to support the notification that an entity has been removed from the stream" - this is because IObservable does not represent a persistant collection, only an asynchronous stream of values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually I found the Reactive-UI library helpful for this (available in NuGet).
This library includes special IObservable subjects for collections and the facility to create one of these 'ReactiveCollections' over a a traditional INCC collection.
Through this I have streams for new, removed items and changing items in the collection.  I then use a Zip to merge the streams together and modify a target ViewModel observable collection.  This provides a live projection based on a query on the source model.

The following code solved the problem (this code would be even simpler, but there are some problems with the Silverlight version of Reactive-UI that needed workarounds).  The code fires collection changed events by simply adjusting the value of 'Rating' on one of the collection elements:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using ReactiveUI;

namespace RxTest
{

    public class TestEntity :  ReactiveObject, INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyPropertyChanging
    {
        public string _File;
        public int _Rating = 0;
        public string File
        {
            get { return _File; }
            set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(x => x.File, value); }
        }

        public int Rating
        {
            get { return this._Rating; }
            set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(x => x.Rating, value); }
        }

        public TestEntity()
        {
        }
    }

    public class TestModel
    {
        private IEnumerable<TestEntity> collection { get; set; }
        private IDisposable sub;

        public TestModel()
        {
            this.collection = new ObservableCollection<TestEntity>() {
            new TestEntity() { File = "MySong.mp3", Rating = 5 },
            new TestEntity() { File = "Heart.mp3", Rating = 5 },
            new TestEntity() { File = "KarmaPolice.mp3", Rating = 5 }};

            var filter = new Func<int, bool>( Rating => (Rating == 0));

            var target = new ObservableCollection<TestEntity>();
            target.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(target_CollectionChanged);
            var react = new ReactiveCollection<TestEntity>(this.collection);
            react.ChangeTrackingEnabled = true;

            // update the target projection collection if an item is added
            react.ItemsAdded.Subscribe( v => { if (filter.Invoke(v.Rating)) target.Add(v); } );
            // update the target projection collection if an item is removed (and it was in the target)
            react.ItemsRemoved.Subscribe(v => { if (filter.Invoke(v.Rating) && target.Contains(v)) target.Remove(v); });

            // track items changed in the collection.  Filter only if the property "Rating" changes
            var ratingChangingStream = react.ItemChanging.Where(i => i.PropertyName == "Rating").Select(i => new { Rating = i.Sender.Rating, Entity = i.Sender });
            var ratingChangedStream = react.ItemChanged.Where(i => i.PropertyName == "Rating").Select(i => new { Rating = i.Sender.Rating, Entity = i.Sender });
            // pair the two streams together for before and after the entity has changed.  Make changes to the target
            Observable.Zip(ratingChangingStream,ratingChangedStream, 
                (changingItem, changedItem) => new { ChangingRating=(int)changingItem.Rating, ChangedRating=(int)changedItem.Rating, Entity=changedItem.Entity})
                .Subscribe(v => { 
                    if (filter.Invoke(v.ChangingRating) && (!filter.Invoke(v.ChangedRating))) target.Remove(v.Entity);
                    if ((!filter.Invoke(v.ChangingRating)) && filter.Invoke(v.ChangedRating)) target.Add(v.Entity);
                });

            // should fire CollectionChanged Add in the target view model collection
            this.collection.ElementAt(0).Rating = 0;
            // should fire CollectionChanged Remove in the target view model collection
            this.collection.ElementAt(0).Rating = 5;
        }

        void target_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Action);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool use of RxUI! One thing I noticed is, ReactiveCollection isn't always a derived collection, it's a subclass of ObservableCollection, so you can just use it directly.

Comment: Thanks Paul.  Noticed a couple of bugs, which I guess are Silverlight specific.  The '.Value' property is not filled out from a ReactiveObject for ItemChanging/Changed (it's set to NULL).  I also had trouble getting ReactiveCollection to track changes on regular INPC objects - using a ReactiveObject fixed that.

Comment: This is for perf reasons - ItemChanging.Value() will give you a stream of values

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with using an `ObservableCollection<T>`? Rx is a very easy framework to overuse; I find that if you find yourself fighting against the basic premise of an asynchronous stream, you probably shouldn't be using Rx for that particular problem.

Comment: Rx is ideal for propagating changes from a model to the ViewModel through to the View.  The features in Rx like thread marshaling,conflation etc make it ideal.

Comment: Based on experience (I've used Rx in a production WPF application), I'd recommend treating (INotifyPropertyChanged) ViewModel properties as "UI", in that that should not be changed from a background thread.

Comment: The features in Rx like thread marshaling,conflation,Subjects etc make it ideal. Just using Rx for the events themselves limits this use and means supporting two paradigms in your code.  

I think the fundamental issue here is that IObservable is not suitable for collections, only the events from a collection.  I still think a generic solution is possible, if the event stream from the collection is 'zipped' with the concat stream from the contents of the collection.

Comment: Richard - I would agree in most cases.  But unfortunately this doesn't scale when doing large, or high frequent model changes.  The Dispatcher is overrun and the UI becomes unresponsive.  This is the attraction of Rx and some of the event stream functions.

Answer (score 1):

All of the INPC implementations that I've ever seen can be best labeled as shortcuts or hacks. However, I can't really fault the developers since the INPC mechanism that the .NET creators choose to support is terrible. With that said, I have recently discovered, in my opinion, the best implementation of INPC, and the best compliment to any MVVM framework around. In addition to providing dozens of extremely helpful functions and extensions, it also sports the most elegant INPC pattern I've seen. It somewhat resembles the ReactiveUI framework, but it wasn't designed to be a comprehensive MVVM platform. To create a ViewModel that supports INPC, it requires no base class, or interfaces, yes is still able to support complete change notification and Two Way binding, and best of all, all of your properties can be automatic!

It does NOT use a utility such as PostSharp or NotifyPropertyWeaver, but is built around the Reactive Extensions framework. The name of this new framework is **ReactiveProperty**. I suggest visiting the project site (on [codeplex](http://reactiveproperty.codeplex.com)), and pulling down the NuGet package. Also, looks through the source code, because it's really a treat.

I'm in no way associated with the developer, and the project is still fairly new. I'm just really enthusiastic about the features it offers.

Comment: ReactiveProperty looks cool, but none of the included samples use a collection of ViewModels or a master-details view, so it's not clear how this library applies to this question (or whether it is useful in the real world, where we often need a UI to edit a collection of objects).

Comment: The library is somewhat new, so missing some documentation is understandable. Admittedly when I posted my response here, I was just picking up the Silverlight/Xaml stack. After much research in other methods, I ended up returning to the library, and still agree with my original post. Which most of the time criticized the INPC implementation, but still within the scope of this discussion. Looking at the source code, a type exists called ReactiveCollection which should directly relate and solidify my thoughts regarding the OP.

Answer (score 0):

To my mind that is not a suitable usage of Rx. An Rx Observable is a stream of 'events' that you can subscribe to. You can react to these events in your View Model, for example adding them to an ObservableCollection which is bound to your view. However, an Observable cannot be used to represent a fixed set of items which you add / remove items from.

Comment: No but the point of ObservableCollection is that it exposes multiple Subjects which represent the operations you can perform on the collection. It's a very elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are looking at the notifications from a List of TestEntitys, not from the TestEntity themselves.  So you see adds, but not changes in any TestEntity. To see this comment out:

```
        if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
```

and you'll see that the program runs the same! Your notifications in your TestEntity's are not wired up to anything. As stated by others, using an ObservableCollection will add this wiring for you.

Comment: FYI, you should always assign an event to a local variable before raising it. Otherwise you can run into a race condition that could throw a NullReferenceException

Comment: Agreed, just trying to keep the code simple (although the INPC support isn't really required).